# Google Apps Script to properly order responses in email

Tags: google-apps-script

I currently have a Google form that when submitted provides a very basic email to a few people with the responses. It works great, however, all of the responses are in a random order. Is there a way to sort them so that I can either have them sent as they are on the form or to decide the order myself?

The fields returned in the sheet are:

- Timestamp
- Email Address
- Site Name
- Address
- ORD
- Approving Person (Drop Down)
- Serial Number
- Affect Item
- Packed (Drop Down)
- Special Instructions

Here is what I currently use:

```
function sendFormByEmail (e)
{
  var email = "email@email.com, email2@email.com";
  var txt = "";
  for (var field in e.namedValues) {
    txt += field + ' :: ' + e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n";
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Part Requested", txt);
}
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what you mean.  Use examples.  What exactly is to be ordered?

Comment: The form has 9 questions which are a mix of type and drop down fields. The fields are:
Site Name,
Address,
ORD,
Approving person (drop down),
Serial Number,
Affected Item,
Packed (Drop down),
Special Instructions

I would like them in that order if possible.

Comment: It would be better for you if you provide that information in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I had edited the post to include that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `e.values` instead of `e.namedValues`, like this:

```js
function sendFormByEmail(e) {
  if (!e) { throw new Error('Run this function through a trigger.'); }
  const emailAddress = 'email@email.com, email2@email.com';
  const fieldNames = ['Timestamp', 'Email Address', 'Site Name', 'Address', 'ORD', 'Approving Person', 'Serial Number', 'Affect Item', 'Packed', 'Special Instructions',];
  const emailBody = e.values
    .map((value, index) => `${fieldNames[index]} :: ${value}`)
    .join('\n\n');
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, 'Part Requested', emailBody);
}
```